# VS Code integrated terminal, how to choose git bash as a default?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code used to show default intagrated terminal as a git bash (I chose it in settings). But after last update August 2021, when I open VS Code I see windows Powershell, but when you click plus it adds git bash. Earlier in both cases there was git bash
Can you give any advise how to choose git bash to be shown when vs code starts?

> `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",`

Comment: if i am right (i dont use vscode anymore) you have to set the path of the full executable, and not the name

Comment: @PyGamer0 it says that the path in full is not accepted

Answer (score 0):

1. At first open command palette by pressing below command

   ctrl + shift + p
2. and search for

   open setting (json)
   [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUlTx.png)
3. then change your setting.json file as below
   [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWckT.png)

4. at last reopen visual studio code.